# Froala wysiwyg-rails, alway remove indent of code when paste to editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wysiwyg, froala

When a copy any code to editor like that

```
<section class="page-title">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7 co-xs-12 text-left">
          <h1><%= t ".title" %></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5 co-xs-12 text-right">
          <div class="bread">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li><%= link_to t(".home"), root_path %></li>
              <li class="active"><%= t ".title" %></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

and in Froala editor display

```
<section class="page-title">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7 co-xs-12 text-left">
<h1><%= t ".title" %></h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5 co-xs-12 text-right">
<div class="bread">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><%= link_to t(".home"), root_path %></li>
<li class="active"><%= t ".title" %></li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Im tried to config but it not work, 
help me please!
im using wysiwyg-rails gem for ROR App